# Why are visited links not rendered differently from non-visited links in AskDifferent?

Tags: bug, design, formatting, hyperlinks

I subscribe to several SE sites. I've noticed that the question links on the Questions page are rendered *differently* on the AskDifferent site than they are on the other sites I visit: After clicking the link to a question, and returning to the Questions page, the question(s) I've read are not rendered in a different color; i.e. visited links are indistinguishable from those that have not been visited. This seems to be true only on the AskDifferent site.

Is this "by design"??

Comment: Retagging this as [bug], since that will draw the attention of Stack Exchange developers.

Comment: @Glorfindel: That's cool... I would've done so, but wasn't certain it was a bug.

Comment: A few sites have visited colors that I find hard to spot, I ended up adding `GM_addStyle (".question-hyperlink:visited { color: green; }");` to a user-script because green seems to be pretty clear on all sites.

Comment: Hi, I was about to post this exactly question, Check this other Stack Exchange site, click on any messages, go back. It is VERY easier to navigate than our AskDifferent. https://gaming.stackexchange.com  Any news about this topic?? Can I put a bounty on this?

Comment: @Prado: Re bounty: I'd save my points... this doesn't seem to be a concern to anyone.